# Querying a database within a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to load some data from a database using PHP, but for some reason it doesn't work when I put it inside a function. If I try the code without a function, it works fine:

```
//$dbc connection
$call1 = 0;
$output = '';
$query = "select * from artists order by lname limit $call1, 15";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $output .= "<ul>";
    $output .= "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
    $output .= "</ul>";
}
```

However, when I change the code to be inside a function, I don't get anything from the database (or at least it won't return anything):

```
//$dbc connection
$call1 = 0;
$output = '';
function loadArtists($call){
    $query = "select * from artists order by lname limit $call, 15";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= "<ul>";
        $output .= "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
        $output .= "</ul>";
    }
}
loadArtists($call1);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check for errors `$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());` but I'd say it's the way you insert the function parameter into your SQL query

Comment: What happens if you try changing `$call` with `0` in your function and then run the function without a parameter, does it work then?

Comment: @bamwebdesign This is irrelevant. This is a scope issue with the connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `$dbc` in your function, because it is a `global` variable.

You can use either

```
function loadArtists($call){
    global $dbc;
    ...
}
```

to make `$dbc` known to `loadArtists()` or pass it as a second parameter

```
function loadArtists($dbc, $call){
...
}
```

and call it as

```
loadArtists($dbc, $call1);
```

Comment: -1 [Using `global` is poor practice.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/679449) The connection should be *passed* to the function.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Aren't `-1` for "wrong answers"? This answer isn't "wrong". So maybe re-consider to just comment about it being bad practice and don't `-1` for what you don't find to be appropriate? Why didn't you just answer that what you say and let say why it's better to use it like that, over `global`.

Comment: @Allendar This answer is *wrong* because it states that the OP ***"must use"*** `global`.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Maybe we don't all take the context of the answers so literal :P Fair enough.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO First of all, thank you for the link. I reworded my answer.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for fixing that. I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche According to PHP there is no need to use `global` outside of a function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @cpattersonv1 I'm not sure, if I got your point, but I clarified the answer with respect to `global`.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in one of my comments, using `global` to fix the scope of your connection [is poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/679449). The *correct* way to pass your connection is like so:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$call1 = 0;
$output = '';
function loadArtists($call, $dbc){
    $query = "select * from artists order by lname limit $call, 15";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= "<ul>";
        $output .= "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
        $output .= "</ul>";
    }
}
loadArtists($call1, $dbc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaring your username and password on the same page as the code you're executing every time you want to make a DB connection is bad practice because:

1. You could potentially have more than one page to edit if you move to a different host or a different environment than the dev environment.
2. If you declare it outside of the root you can limit access to the DB password from FTP accounts.

I like to use a function for the connection so this way if the connection closes you can reopen it at will (reducing server overhead). Also you don't have to set it as a global var inside the function ([not a good idea because of several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527)).

So for those reasons, this connection should be outside (below) the root.

**/../safe/connection.php**

```
function openSQL() {
  $conn = mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
  return $conn;
}
```

**functions.php**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../safe/connection.php');
function loadArtists($call){
   $dbc = openSQL();
   $query = "select * from artists order by lname limit $call, 15";
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $output .= "<ul>";
      $output .= "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
      $output .= "</ul>";
   }
   mysqli_close($dbc);
   return $output;
}

$myOutput = loadArtists(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). That variable does not exist *within* your function.

There are three ways to deal with that:

1. Make it global, that means an outside variable is readible from within a function. (Note that using global variables is often considered a security concern.)

   ```
   global $dbc;
   ```
2. You can pass that variable into the function as an argument

   ```
   function loadArtists($connection, $call) { ... }
   ```
3. you can make a class and that class variable will now be useable inside of class functions:

   ```
   class Artists {
       public $dbc;
       public function __construct() {
           $this->dbc = open_the_db_connection(); //etc?
       }
       public function loadArtists($call) {
           $query = "select * from artists order by lname limit $call, 15";
           $result = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               $output .= "<ul>";
               $output .= "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
               $output .= "</ul>";
           }
           return $output;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a scoping issue to me. The $output you reference in the function isn't the same as the $output you defined outside the function.

You should change your function to the following:

```
function loadArtists($call){
$output = "";
$query = "select * from artists order by lname limit $call, 15";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $output .= "<ul>";
    $output .= "<li>" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
    $output .= "</ul>";
}

return $output;
```

}

$output = loadArtists($call1);